# How enable ruler in google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I develop some project and can't use "ruler" functional in google maps. I searched in documentation. 
Tell me please how I can enable it or how to use the API. Maybe there will be some example. Thanks.
Example of a functional: http://prntscr.com/ihur9q

Answer (score 2):

I hope you are asking about scalecontrol. It is disabled by default, but we can enable it.

The following example sets the map to hide the Zoom control and display the Scale control. Note that we do not explicitly disable the default UI, so these modifications are additive to the default UI behavior.

```
function initMap() 
{
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
   {
      zoom: 4,
      center: {lat: -33, lng: 151},
      zoomControl: false,
      scaleControl: true
  });

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggested edit, Sasikumar Murugesan.